# Altering Mysql column default value to CURRENT_DATE gives error?

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE `mysystem`.`projects` 
MODIFY COLUMN `project_capture_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE();
```

gives:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE()'
 at line 2
```

Current row definition:

```
project_capture_date, date, NO, , 0000-00-00
```

Just recently changed the engine to `InnoDB` from `MyISAM`.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `mysystem`.`projects` 
MODIFY COLUMN `project_capture_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Answer (score 1):

As per the mysql document

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

> The DEFAULT value clause in a data type specification indicates a
>   default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must
>   be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means,
>   for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be
>   the value of a function such as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception
>   is that you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a
>   TIMESTAMP

To solve this you may need to define the datatype as TIMESTAMP column with DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/655c7b/1)**

If you do not want TIMESTAMP then you have do while inserting by setting the column value as Now()

Comment: oh I checked here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html, and it seemed that `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` was in the same boat as `CURRENT_DATE`. Thanks for pointing out that exception.

Comment: I see that confuses you i.e the list of functions. But yes right now for default the only option is  TIMESTAMP with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default.

Answer (score 0):

As per the MySQL 8.0.13 documentation, you can add CURRENT_DATE() as default by enclosing them in parentheses.

> The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN column_name DATE DEFAULT (CURDATE());
```

Please note: `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURRENT_DATE()` are synonyms for `CURDATE()`.

You can use any of them.